# MvvmCross / MvxNotifyTask callback on task finished

Tags: android, mvvmcross

Let's assume I have `MvxNotifyTask` used like here:

```
MyCommand = new MvxCommand(
   MyTask = MvxNotifyTask.Create(
      asyncAction: () => MyLoooongRunningAsync(),
      onException: ex => OnTaskException(ex)
   );
)
```

`MyCommand` is executed after button click.
After `MyLoooongRunningAsync` I want to call sth like this (in short):

```
myTextView.Text = "task done";
```

Where should I put this call?
Does `MvxNotifyTask` support calling action after task is done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not have that, but you can just wrap your task in another one and make the after action there, e.g.:

```cs
MyCommand = new MvxCommand(
   MyTask = MvxNotifyTask.Create(
      asyncAction: () => MyTask(),
      onException: ex => OnTaskException(ex)
   );
)

private async Task MyTask()
{
    await MyLoooongRunningAsync();
    myTextView.Text = "task done";
}
```

HIH

Comment: Tnx. Good workaround as `MvxNotifyTask` doesn't give this ability. I decided to pick different approach - added as another answer.

Comment: welcome, even though I don't think it's a workaround, because I don't see the need of `MvxNotifyTask` to have this, given that you can treat it as any other sequential actions in tasks, you just await the task and after that you continue with the action